# Check if the values from a second column differ from the standard settings in case the values from the first column do

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
          A                B               C
1     Currency          FX-Rate
2       EUR               1.0
3       EUR               1.0
----------------------------------------------------------
4       USD               2.5
5       USD               1.0
6       USD               1.0
----------------------------------------------------------
7       EUR               1.0
8       EUR               1.0
9       EUR               1.0
```

In **Column A** the user enters a currency. In **Column B** automatically 1.0 is selected as the FX-Rate. In the standard setting **EUR** is the basic currency.

The user can now change the currency in **Column A** to a foreign currency. In this case above **USD** is considered as the foreign currency.

Once the user changes the currency from **EUR** to **USD** he should be required to change the FX-Rate in **Column B** as well.

In order to ensure a correct entry from the user I want to have a `check cell` in **C1** that automatically shows an "Error" in case in **Column A** the user defines another currency but forgets to change the FX-Rate from 1.0 to another value. Therefore, I developed the following formula:

```
   C1 = IF(SUM(B2:B10)=COUNTIF(A2:A10,">"&""""),"Error","O.K.")
```

However, this formula only works if there is only one row in another currency. As soon as there is another row with a foreign currency *(as in my example above)* the formula shows "O.K." instead of an "Error".

Do you have any idea what I have to change in my formula to make the `check cell` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Cell C1` try

```
=IF((SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10<>"EUR")*(B2:B10=1)))+(SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10="EUR")*(B2:B10<>1)))>0,"Error","OK")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Perfect solution.

Comment: Hey Mrig, do you also have an idea for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239399/check-if-subsequent-values-in-a-list-differ-from-the-first-defined-value-in-the?noredirect=1#comment79442426_46239399

Answer (score 0):

please use this formula in `C` column.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1,$H$1:$I$2,2,FALSE)-B1<>0,"False","OK")
```

[image]

You could even simplify it a bit, and use `Vlookup` in Column `B`, which eliminates user need to manually input currency.